# how to disable shell log outputs in qhull lib used inside Point Cloud Library

Tags: pcl, qhull

When i use Convex Hull in PCL I get a low of undesired outputs like

Convex hull of 81350 points in 2-d:

Number of vertices: 24
Number of facets: 24

Statistics for:  | qhull FA

Number of points processed: 24
Number of hyperplanes created: 46
Number of distance tests for qhull: 540934
CPU seconds to compute hull (after input): 0.005
Total facet area:   0.56994136
Total volume:       0.017731251

how to disable them?

I don't see an option

thanks